# MySQL View cannot be executed via shell command

Tags: php, mysql, shell, cakephp

I have a PHP script (CakePHP framework) that makes this call

```
$data_reports = Cache::read('get_data_reports', 'short');
if (!$data_reports) {
    $data_reports = $this->paginate('DataReport');
    Cache::write('get_data_reports', $data_reports, 'short');
}
```

where `DataReport` model uses a View named data_report_v in the database.

When executing the script via the browser, it works fine - I got data being returned and cached.

However, if I execute the script from the shell, retrieving data from `data_report_v` view won't work. Also, if I replace that view call with the actual query (that is wrapped within the view itself), the shell command can now execute that and return results.

What is the problem here?

Comment: `However, if I execute the script from the shell` How are you doing that? What _does_ happen? Look at the sql log.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get request failed: action not performing its duty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32961998/get-request-failed-action-not-performing-its-duty)